# Android: Textview out of boundary

Tags: android, xml, layout, textview

I have been trying to make this Layout which contains a Textview in a TableLayout. The textview however doesn't fit inside the layout. It goes out of the boundary. Changing the width to fill_parent or wrap_content doesn't seem to fix it.

Please see this [screenshot](http://s13.postimg.org/yeb7aib3r/Screen_Shot_2013_05_08_at_12_02_33_PM.png)

The following is the xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ReportDetailActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/camera_icon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewCategory"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Pothole"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Comment : "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewComment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Location : "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="aaaaaadsk jfshdfhsdkh fdsfdshfkdshfk hsdkhfk sdhkfhsd;kfhs"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date : "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add the layout_weight;

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Location : "
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="aaaaaadsk jfshdfhsdkh fdsfdshfkdshfk hsdkhfk sdhkfhsd;kfhs"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving fix width to the textview. This will prevent from text going off the screen:

```
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Location : "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewLocation"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="aaaaaadsk jfshdfhsdkh fdsfdshfkdshfk hsdkhfk sdhkfhsd;kfhs"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ReportDetailActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/camera_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewCategory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Pothole"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Comment : "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewComment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Location : "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewLocation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="aaaaaadsk jfshdfhsdkh fdsfdshfkdshfk hsdkhfk sdhkfhsd;kfhs"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date : "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set fix layout_width to your textview and set maxlines or minlines attribute if needed.